# How can i fetch and display the value from external page to parent page's html element

Tags: php

Here is my `first.php` and `second.php`

Where i am just submitting the form itself, but i am including the second.php file which has the function `get()` which wil return 'ok'.

So I am calling the `get()` function after the form is posted.

**Now how can I get the values and display it in the text `fetchedvalue` ?**

**first.php**

```
<?php
include 'second.php';
?>
<form method="post" action="">
<input type="text" name="fetchedvalue">
<input type="submit" name="login" value="Submit">
</form>
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
get();
}
?>
```

**second.php**

```
<?php
function get()
{
  echo 'ok';
}
```

**Note :**

I have many data like that, How can I do it in a single form submit and fill all such textbox ?

Answer (score 1):

try using this method:

```
<?php
  include 'second.php';
  $fvalue = '';
  if(isset($_POST['fetchedvalue']))
    $fvalue = $_POST['fetchedvalue'];
?>
<form method="post" action="">
  <input type="text" name="fetchedvalue" value="<?=$fvalue;?>">
  <input type="submit" name="login" value="Submit">
</form>
<?php
  if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
  {
    get();
  }
?>
```

notice that `$fvalue` is the variable responsible for creating value in the "fetchedvalue" input tag.. if the post is still not done, then the value would be "".

Comment: Don't forget to validate/filter input data. Maybe use [htmlspecialchars](http://us.php.net/htmlspecialchars)?

Answer (score 0):

You can access the variables by using `$_POST` like an array, so:

```
$fetchedValue = $_POST['fetchedvalue'];
```

Though, a safer approach would be the following:

```
<?php
include 'second.php';

$fetchedValue = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'fetchedvalue', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

?>

<form method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" name="fetchedvalue" value="<?php echo $fetchedValue; ?>">
    <input type="submit" name="login" value="Submit">
</form>
```

`filter_input()` will return `null` if no POST variable with the given name is defined, and if it is, it will apply some sanitation or validation on it. Have a look at the manual for more detailed information:

http://php.net/filter_input

Comment: but you should first check it with `isset()` function before assigning to a variable to avoid undefined errors..

Comment: @catzilla Good point - I was just updating my answer as you posted it :)

Answer (score 0):

$_POST['fetchedvalue'] will contain it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && isset($_POST['login']))
{
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($_POST); // Here you will get all posted values & then you can call get method
    echo "</pre>";
    get();   
}
?>
```